# mongodb script file prints result along with log

Tags: mongodb, nosql

bank_data collection has 6 records in it. so i am expecting the output should show only 6. but the `6` is printed along with timestamp and other text log.

**script.js** has following code

```
use test;
db.bank_data.find({first_name : "logan"}).count();
```

ran the above file in command line

```
mongo --quiet script.js > result.txt
```

**Output** result.txt file has following out put

```
2015-05-27T17:12:09.752+0530 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is installed, no need to zero-out data files
switched to db test
6
```

I need to print the value alone `6`

Answer (score 0):

This should work , eval option is one way to get this done:

> mongo test --quiet --eval "printjson(db.bank_data.find({first_name :
>   "logan"}).count())" > result.txt